# How to setup error and 404 pages in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I created `_error.js` page file:

```
function CustomError({ statusCode }) {
  return (
    <figure>
      <figcaption>
        <h1>{statusCode}</h1>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  );
}

export default CustomError;
```

Also 404.js page:

```
export default function Custom404() {
  return <h1>404 - Page Not Found</h1>
}
```

How to make that pages work and appear when something is not wrong?

Should I have some logic for that on every page?

Comment: "How to make that pages work and appear when something is not wrong?". It this a typo on your end or something, I don't understand why would you want to show an error page when something is not wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The`_error.js` page is automatically picked up by NextJS - no action is necessary.

To test

1. For 404 pages , just pass a invalid path and you will see the page - Make sure you have named it `pages/404.js` else you will get the `_error.js` page

   2. For the error pages - You can throw an error or mistype a statement that would thrown an error, you will see the error within the boundary of the component or the entire container